# Como trabalhar com variáveis de ambiente no ReactJS

Tags: node.js, react

Olá!

Estou começando agora com ReacJS.

Geralmente no NodeJS eu crio uma pasta `environments` e coloco o `index.ts` ou `index.example.ts`, com os valores lá

```
DB=nome_banco
HOST=localhost
USER=username
```

Quando comecei a usar ReactJS eu tentei usar a mesma lógica, criando a pasta e os arquivos para usar a api

```
dev

HOST=http://localhost:3000

prod

HOST=http::/dominio.com.br:1234
```

Toda vez, antes de eu dar o build eu tenho que ir no environments mudar o host.

Tentei usar esse [tutorial](https://dev.to/jam3/managing-env-variables-for-provisional-builds-h37), até deu certo para o localhost, criei dois arquivos env.development e env.production com seguinte conteudo de exemplo:

**Development**

```
REACT_APP_HOST=http://localhost:3001
```

**Production**

```
REACT_APP_HOST=http://dominio.com.br:1234
```

E coloquei no package.json o seguinte:

```
"scripts": {        
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build"
  },
```

Mas ao dar o build, só pega os dados do localhost

Onde posso estar errando?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O Create React App aceita os seguintes arquivos por padrão, sem precisar instalar o `env-cmd`:

- `.env`: padrão.
- `.env.local`: Sobreposições locais. Esse arquivo é carregado para
  todos os ambientes, exceto test.
- `.env.development`, `.env.test`, `.env.production`: Configurações
  específicas de cada ambiente.
- `.env.development.local`, `.env.test.local`, `.env.production.local`:
  Sobreposições locais de configuração para cada ambiente específico.

O que testei e funcionou:

- criar projeto CRA:

  ```
  npx create-react-app my-app
  cd my-app
  ```
- criar o arquivo `.env.development` com o conteúdo

  `REACT_APP_HOST=http://localhost:3001`
- criar o arquivo `.env.production` com o conteúdo

  `REACT_APP_HOST=http://dominio.com.br:1234`
- no código do app, usar a variável `process.env.REACT_APP_HOST`.
- Sem alterar os comandos de start e build e ao executar `npm start`, a
  variável aparece conforme definida no ambiente de development. Ao executar `npm run build`, a variável aparece conforme definida no ambiente de production.

Não se esqueça que ao alterar o arquivo de produção, é preciso recompilar o projeto para surtir efeito.

**Documentação oficial**: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: Sempre que eu quiser um parâmetro tenho que usar `REAT_APP_` no prefixo?

Comment: Sim. Você deve sempre prefixar as variáveis que serão usadas no CRA com `REACT_APP_`. Quaisquer outras variáveis, exceto aquelas prefixadas por `NODE_ENV` (readonly) serão ignoradas. A razão é que alguns projetos usam o mesmo `.env` pro React e pro backend. Daí, um password de banco de dados que está num `.env` poderia ser exposto no bundle de produção, já que as variáveis são "hardcodadas" na compilação final. Isto é, jamais escreva um `REAT_APP_SEGREDO_ULTRA_SECRETO`.

Comment: Exemplo: https://i.imgur.com/jnnger0.png

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo

Comment: Não funcionou comigo aparece o seguinte erro no console: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at authConfig.ts:5:19

Answer (score -1):

Se você não criou a sua aplicação usando o Create React App, usou o **Vite**, siga estas etapas para configurar variáveis de ambiente:

- Crie um arquivo `.env` e adicione a variável chamada `VITE_API_URL`.
  Lembre-se de adicionar o prefixo `VITE_` ao nome da variável de
  ambiente.
- Em seguida, no seu código React, você pode acessar a variável de
  ambiente diretamente usando o objeto `import.meta.env`.

**Resumo: Use `import.meta.env` para acessar a variável de ambiente e adicione o prefixo `VITE_` no nome da variável.**